# How to force update a field from model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I would like to know how to force update field `price_subtotal` in `sale_order_line` model. It is computed from several modules but I would like to be able to update it from my custom module. By clicking a button, the field gets updated to a certain number that I calculated.

I tried (creation part is successful)

```
sale_order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create({...})
sale_order_line.update({
  'price_subtotal': 1234,
})
```

I also tried putting the field update within the creation part. None of these methods update the field.

I need a way to force update the field.

Comment: When you force the value of the field, what should be the new value of `product_uom_qty` or `price_unit`?

Comment: @Kenly Their values should stay the same. I only need to change `price_subtotal`. Currently, I do not have a good way to do it; so, I accept the only answer there. If you have a solution for this, I will consider changing the accepted answer accordingly.

Comment: According to Odoo docs: `To allow setting values on a computed field, use the inverse parameter. It is the name of a function reversing the computation and setting the relevant fields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can not write computed fields not even forcefully.** These fields are used in later processes and they have to be accurate and that is why it is computed.

**But if you want to update these fields anyway,** there are a few ways to do that.

**1. Inherit Compute Method :** You can inherit field's compute method in your custom module and change or overwrite calculation of it however you want.

**2. Overwrite Field :** You can overwrite field in your custom module, defile field with same name in same module and do not write compute="" in definition. It will overwrite base field when your custom module is installed.

**3. Replace The Field :** Create a new field in your custom module. Inherit view and hide base field and show your field there. This can be used for visibility purpose only. In next processes like invoices etc, original base field values will be taken.

These are the ways you can manipulate calculation of base computed field in Odoo. But **I do not recommend it, I suggest** check configurations and check compute method to understand how you can get your desired value in that computed field.

Comment: I think you forgot one other nice possibility or another variant of your first one: create a new field which is filled on the button call and use this field in the overridden compute method. And writing to computed fields is "common" in newer odoo versions. A lot of normal fields were made to computed ones there, but with `readonly=False`.

Comment: readonly=False does not affect when field is not editable because it is computed field.  Kindly check.
readonly=False  can be useful only if readonly=True or readonly="condition" applied from base.

Comment: I didn't want to write everything down in a comment. [Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1b504038ce270540ddab28db4ab995d22f2ab2a7/addons/sale/models/sale_order.py#L137-L142) you can see one example. In older verions this was not computed and it's editable in view.